# How to store authentication bearer token in browser cookie using AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-identity

I have created a bearer token using ASP.net Identity. In AngularJS I wrote this function to get authorized data.

```
$scope.GetAuthorizeData = function () {
  $http({
    method: 'GET',
    url: "/api/Values",
    headers: { 'authorization': 'bearer <myTokenId>' },
  }).success(function (data) {
    alert("Authorized :D");
    $scope.values = data;
  }).error(function () {
    alert("Failed :(");
  });
};
```

So **I want to store this token into Browser cookies**. If this token is present there , then take the token and get the data from IIS server Otherwise redirect to login page to login to get a new token.

Similarly, if user click onto log out button, it should remove the token from browser cookie.

**How to do this ? It it possible ? Is it proper way to authenticate and authorize a user ? What to do if there are multiple users token ?**

Answer (score 19, accepted):

There is a `$cookies` service available in the AngularJS API using the 
`ngCookies` module. It can be used like below:

```
function controller($cookies) {
    //set cookie
    $cookies.put('token', 'myBearerToken');

    //get cookie
    var token=$cookies.get('token');

    //remove token
    $cookies.remove('token');
}
controller.$inject=['$cookies'];
```

For your case it would be:

```
//inject $cookies into controller
$scope.GetAuthorizeData = function () {
    $http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: "/api/Values",
        headers: { 'authorization': 'bearer <myTokenId>' },
    })
    .success(function (data) {
        $cookies.put('token', data);
    }).error(function () {
        alert("Failed :(");
    });
};
```

You will also have to add the [angular-cookies module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-cookies) code. And add it to your angular app: `angular.module('myApp', ['ngCookies']);`. [Docs for Angular Cookies.](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngCookies/service/$cookies)

I would also like to suggest the usage of a `Http interceptor` which will set the bearer header for each request, rather than having to manually set it yourself for each request.

```
//Create a http interceptor factory
function accessTokenHttpInterceptor($cookies) {
    return {
        //For each request the interceptor will set the bearer token header.
        request: function($config) {
            //Fetch token from cookie
            var token=$cookies.get['token'];

            //set authorization header
            $config.headers['Authorization'] = 'Bearer '+token;
            return $config;
        },
        response: function(response) {
            //if you get a token back in your response you can use 
            //the response interceptor to update the token in the 
            //stored in the cookie
            if (response.config.headers.yourTokenProperty) {
                  //fetch token
                  var token=response.config.headers.yourTokenProperty;

                  //set token
                  $cookies.put('token', token);
            }
            return response;
        }
    };
}
accessTokenHttpInterceptor.$inject=['$cookies'];

//Register the http interceptor to angular config.
function httpInterceptorRegistry($httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.interceptors.push('accessTokenHttpInterceptor');
}
httpInterceptorRegistry.$inject=['$httpProvider'];

//Assign to module
angular
    .module('myApp')
    .config(httpInterceptorRegistry)
    .factory('accessTokenHttpInterceptor', accessTokenHttpInterceptor)
```

Having the `http interceptor` in place you do not need to set the `Authorization header` for each request.

```
function service($http) {
    this.fetchToken=function() {
        //Authorization header will be set before sending request.
        return $http
            .get("/api/some/endpoint")
            .success(function(data) {
                 console.log(data);
                 return data;
            })
    }
}
service.$inject=['$http']
```

As stated by Boris: there are other ways to solve this. You could also use `localStorage` to store the token. This can also be used with the http interceptor. Just change the implementation from cookies to localStorage.

```
function controller($window) {
    //set token
    $window.localStorage['jwt']="myToken";

    //get token
    var token=$window.localStorage['jwt'];
}
controller.$inject=['$window'];
```

Comment: Ya.Got it. Thank you. Nice explanation.

Comment: Hello, where will `<myTokenId>` be? where to find it?

Answer (score 18):

I would advise against keeping the data in a cookie, for security purposes you should set the cookies to secure and HttpOnly (not accessible from javascript). If you're not using SSL, I would suggest moving to `https`.

I would pass the token from the auth endpoint in a json response:

```
{
    tokenData: 'token'
}
```

You can save the token data in `sessionStorage` by using the `$window` service:

```
$window.sessionStorage.setItem('userInfo-token', 'tokenData');
```

It will be cleared once the user closes the page, and you can manually remove it by setting it to empty string:

```
$window.sessionStorage.setItem('userInfo-token', '');
```

Edit:

Interceptor implementation for catching data, adapted from cbass (not tested, you can inspect the objects for response/request to fiddle with the information):

```
//Create a http interceptor factory
function accessTokenHttpInterceptor($window) {
    return {
        //For each request the interceptor will set the bearer token header.
        request: function($config) {
            //Fetch token from cookie
            var token=$window.sessionStorage.getItem('userInfo-token');

            //set authorization header
            $config.headers['Authorization'] = 'Bearer '+token;
            return $config;
        },
        response: function(response) {
            //if you get a token back in your response you can use 
            //the response interceptor to update the token in the 
            //stored in the cookie
            if (response.config.url === 'api/token' && response.config.data.tokenData) {
                  //fetch token
                  var token=response.config.data.tokenData;

                  //set token
                  $window.sessionStorage.setItem('userInfo-token', token);
            }
            return response;
        }
    };
}

accessTokenHttpInterceptor.$inject=['$window'];
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have not tried $window yet in angular JS.Neither have any idea to use SSL. Where should I write these codes? Can you give me more clear answer .

Comment: You can put the handlers for session storage in a service, or like cbass mentions below using a httpInterceptor.

Comment: Saving the token in the session storage means also that if I open a link in a new tab the token from the session storage isn't available. The user would need to authenticate again (on every tab) which is really annoying. Possible solution: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32766809/1878249

Comment: @goflo that's right depending on how the new tab gets opened (it must be a new browsing context so the `sessionStorage` is not shared). The fallback with `localStorage` would be useful for such a case. Another alternative with using `window.name` to keep the data which I find a questionable technique and would consider a last resort. That being said I didn't experience any issue with opening new tabs in my app. But I may have had a slightly different configuration than described above (it's been more than six months since I've touched that code).