# Unable to clear access token after log out

Tags: java, angularjs, authentication, access-token, logout

I am unable to clear access token event after logging out. I just created method which is clearing whole user object and redirecting to login page when clicking on logout button.

```
$scope.logout = function(){

    $scope.user ={};
    $state.go('static.login');
    $(".loader").fadeOut("slow");

}
```

Still I able to see access token in Application tab while inspecting login page.

[image]

Above is image that can show, And I able to see last logged in user object details while debugging after clicking submit without entering any credentials.As you can see below.

[image]

```
$scope.setCookie = function(cname, cvalue, exMins) {
    var d = new Date();
    d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exMins*60*1000));
    var expires = "expires="+d.toUTCString();  
    document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + ";" + expires + ";path=/";
}
```

after modification of logout method. clearing access token.

```
$scope.logout = function(){

    /*
    $state.go('static.login');
    $(".loader").fadeOut("slow");*/
      //var token=$cookies.get('ACCESS_TOKEN');
      $cookies.remove('ACCESS_TOKEN');
      $scope.user={};
      $state.go('static.login');

}
```

Comment: Is it cached at client? /browser's generally cache this locally, so you may want to clear it or just close the windows and open to check if it still exists?

Comment: Where is the code for token clear?

Comment: But, I am clearing my cache using Empty Cache hard reload,Still it is showing

Comment: Should I write separate code for clearing access token instead of clearing whole user object?

Comment: Check your cookies expiry time

Comment: It is better to use session storage for token

Comment: Do I need to change anything in Authentication Interceptor?As I edited  you can see my cookie time in question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34545875/how-to-store-authentication-bearer-token-in-browser-cookie-using-angularjs) for your problem

Sample

```
//remove token
$cookies.remove('token');
```

Comment: I able to clear access token But, I am unable to clear  last logged in user object. You can see in question how I did.

Comment: yes, after log out I checked user object in debugging by clicking login   without entering any credentials then too object consists user details.

Comment: During login you are storing data in $rootScope as per your screenshot so change logout code and write `$rootScope.user = {}`