# Why is my angular application, using the ngx-cookie-service and jwt, not working with IIS?

Tags: angular, iis, jwt, ngx-cookie-service

After deployment on IIS, the Ngx-cookie-service is not functioning. The browser cookie does not store my token. Is there a setting or configuration that has to be made on IIS?

But when I simply run in my IDE using Visual Studio Code, it works.

Comment: After deploying to IIS, are there any other unexpected errors? Besides, you need to check if it is deployed correctly. You can refer to this about store token into Browser cookies: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34545875/how-to-store-authentication-bearer-token-in-browser-cookie-using-angularjs.