# Sharing sessionStorage between tabs in Angular 2 then immediately using it?

Tags: http, angular, typescript, sessionstorage

**What I already know:**

- I can share `sessionStorage` between browser tabs using the solution
  found here:
  [browser sessionStorage. share between tabs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20325763/browser-sessionstorage-share-between-tabs?answertab=active#tab-top)

**What I use:**

- **Angular 2** (v2.4.4) with **TypeScript** on **Angular CLI** base

**The actual problem:**

The script (which shares the `sessionStorage` between tabs) runs within Angular before HTTP requests, but when the page creates a HTTP request, it uses a session id (which is sent to the server in order to identify the session) and **the session id should be taken from `sessionStorage`, but it is not there yet**.

When I open the browser's debugger console (on the new tab), the `sessionStorage` is there. And because of this when I reload this new tab everything works just fine. **But the problem is that the `sessionStorage` was set *after* HTTP request already tried to use.**

The above linked solution truly runs before HTTP calls, but the *event* calls happen after HTTP calls. I think about especial `sessionStorage_transfer` from the above linked code:

```
window.addEventListener("storage", sessionStorage_transfer, false);
```

I store the session id like this:

```
get sid(): string {
    return sessionStorage.getItem('user.sid') || '';
}
set sid(value: string) {
    sessionStorage.setItem('user.sid', value);
}
```

So eventually `sid` receives value but just after the HTTP call already tried to use it despite the fact that the script (which shares `sessionStorage`) started to run before any HTTP call.

(If there is no solution then I will use session cookie for `sid` alone but I hope someone knows a solution for this. Perhaps a Promise, Observable, Subject, anything?)

Thank you for your solutions! :-)

Comment: New tab has its own sessionStorage and it should not come anything from previous tab. I think http request gives you new sid, which is set in new tab's sessionStorage and you think it comes from previous tab.

Comment: I know that `sessionStorage` does not come from previous tab. That is the actual problem: I need the `sessionStorage` from the previous tab! I don't want to store the session variables in cookies, but in the `sessionStorage`, but it is not available on the other tab...

Comment: There is good explanation: http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/80727/best-place-to-store-authentication-tokens-client-side

Answer (score 1):

keep the code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20325763/browser-sessionstorage-share-between-tabs) mentioned in correct answer in your index.html of your angular web-app. It worked for me.