# Stop duplicate tabs opening using js

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome

I'm using jquery-session.js package to stop the multi tabs opening of the same url.

```
var key = "TabCount";
var value = "xx";
$.session.set(key, value);
```

checking value in another tab

```
var checksession = $.session.get('TabCount');
if (checksession == undefined) {
 // alert('Same tab is opened');
 }
```

but if I'm opening the tab by right click and selecting duplicate option session value is restored and the same tab can be opened.
how can I stop this?

Comment: why don't you just support multiple tabs as the rest of the world?

Comment: This is product requirement to open only one tab of the same URL

Comment: This might help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20325763/browser-sessionstorage-share-between-tabs