# how can I transfer session storage from window to another or from tab to tab using angular 4?

Tags: angular, typescript, local-storage, sessionstorage

I have some values in my site which i want to clear when browser is close, i chose session Storage to store that values, it clear when tab is close and keep storing if user reload the page , but if user open some link in different tab this values unavailable. How i can share session Storage values between all browser tabs with my application using angular 4?

The use case: put value in some storage, keep that value accessible in all browser tabs and clear it if all tabs is closed.

Comment: check this  [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20325763/browser-sessionstorage-share-between-tabs)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [browser sessionStorage. share between tabs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20325763/browser-sessionstorage-share-between-tabs)

Comment: i checked this solution but i don't know how can i apply this solution with type script on angular 4 @FatehMohamed