# Window.open is creating new session in JSP

Tags: javascript, java, jsp, session, cookies

I have app running in IE mode in EDGE and i have one JSP page which opens in EDGE with window.open. My problem is when the new JSP page opens in EDGE it creates new session. How can I force JSP to not open new session and keep the original session. Because window.open() takes a new session and all the session variables are lost.
So far i have tried with below code but it didnt work.

```
var url = "microsoft-edge:http://"+window.location.host+"/map.jsp?"+markers+"$"+"tyer";
          document.cookie = "JSESSIONID=<%=id%>; domain=window.location.host"
          window.open(url);
```

I want the main JSP page and new page in EDGE to have same session both are running under same domain.

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20325763/browser-sessionstorage-share-between-tabs. Hope it helps you

Comment: @bovop4 i dont have two tabs i have two browser, one is in IE Mode in edge and second is in EDGE.

Comment: You can't share that between two browsers

Comment: @bovop4 so there is no way to keep the same session in two browser ?